# Issue in create controller

Tags: magento2, url, controllers

I am trying to create a custom controller in magento 2.1. I have created routes.xml and namespace as

routes.xml

```
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
        <router id="standard">
            <route id="customattribute" frontName="customattribute">
                <module name="Namespace_Modulename" />
            </route>
        </router>
    </config>
```

controller

```
namespace namespace\modulename\Controller\Searchajax;

    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        /**
         * say hello text
         */

         public function execute()
        {
            return 'Hello world!';
        }

    }
```

in my controller file. But I am not getting the required result. Please suggest to me a way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your routes.xml code

Comment: @Rakesh I updated my question

Comment: inside controller have you print anything?

Comment: @Rakesh when i run the url its going 404

Comment: plz show your url string for me now

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass url like below,

**`<?php echo $this->getUrl('customattribute/searchajax/index'); ?>`**

Now inside your controller file, you can debug more inside **execute** function.

Comment: It returns 404 url

Comment: Have you used above url?

Answer (score 2):

problem in xml `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
        <router id="standard">
            <route id="customattribute" frontName="customattribute">
                <module name="Namespace_Modulename" />
            </route>
        </router>
</config>
```

controller code return the json array

```
namespace namespace\modulename\Controller\Searchajax;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        /**
         * say hello text
         */

         public function execute()
        {
            $data=array('a','b','c');
            $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
            $resultJson->setData($data);
            return $resultJson;
        }

    }
```

Comment: How to return array in my controller?

Comment: @DeebanBabu added the json array code..